# jquery push condition in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with one code dont know why its not working please suggests me

I push condition in array like

```
var condition = [];
if(performer !== "All" ){
    condition.push("(($( this ).attr('performer') === $.trim(performer)))");
}
if(music !== "All" ){
    condition.push("(($( this ).attr('music') === $.trim(music)))");
}
if(collector !== "All" ){
    condition.push("(($( this ).attr('collector') === $.trim(collector)))");
}
if(clickedThemeArray.toString() !== "All"){
    condition.push("(arraysEqual(themeArray,clickedThemeArray))");
}
console.log(condition.join(" && "));
```

And then join with && like this

```
var finalCon = condition.join(" && ");
if(finalCon){
    $( this ).addClass('displayBlock');
}
```

But its not working please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the double quotes

```
condition.push("(($( this ).attr('performer') === $.trim(performer)))");
```

should be

```
condition.push($( this ).attr('performer') === $.trim(performer));
```

and so on.

Otherwise they will be evaluated as **strings** instead of **booleans**.

Comment: Well, if you look at the whole question, the asker is combining those strings that he is pushing to the array at the end, and trying to check that resultant string. Would this be a case when eval would need to be used?

Comment: yes but when i get rid of double quotes it give me boolean value but i need those condition to generate final if condition on the basis of previous if conditions

Comment: @Zack . I don't think the OP is trying to evaluate using eval. As it seems to be a simple if condition.

Comment: @Sushanth-- that's what I'm saying. sismaster is not using eval, but when evaluating string expressions, you should use eval.

Comment: Right that is one way to do it... But don't think we require that here and they can be evaluated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing your conditions in the array as strings by adding those double quotes. Hence, when you combine them with the `&&` they do not work as expected.

Writing
`condition.push( $(this).attr('performer') === $.trim(performer) );`
should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep a running variable instead:

```
var passedConditions = true;
if(performer !== "All" ){
    passedConditions = passedConditions && $( this ).attr('performer') === $.trim(performer);
}
if(music !== "All" ){
    passedConditions = passedConditions && $( this ).attr('music') === $.trim(music);
}
if(collector !== "All" ){
    passedConditions = passedConditions && $( this ).attr('collector') === $.trim(collector);
}
if(clickedThemeArray.toString() !== "All"){
    passedConditions = passedConditions && arraysEqual(themeArray,clickedThemeArray);
}

if (passedConditions) {
    $( this ).addClass('displayBlock');
}
```